# Python QuTiP Saving Bloch sphere as .png and .pdf

Tags: python

When I generate a simple Bloch sphere with Python's QuTiP, I can save the figure as either .png or .pdf:

```
from qutip import *    

b = Bloch()

b.show()

bb = b.fig
bb.savefig('Bloch.png')
bb.savefig('Bloch.pdf')
```

The resulting files are quite different. The .png looks like:

[image: Bloch.png]

whereas the .pdf shows much darker lines:

[image]

Is there a way to make the .pdf figure look more like that of the .png?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your PDF viewer I am using Foxit and They are the same:
[press the link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erTe3.png)